# How to get DNIS in a UCMA 3.0 application

Tags: lync-2010, ucma

I'm developing IVR application by using UCMA 3 But not using lync server. When audio or video call is received i need to get DNIS of that. Is there any way to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to take long time to post my own answer.
I found feasible solution(not sure is that perfect) for this. You can retrieve ANI and DNIS details in indirect manner by using CallRecievedEventArgs argument. To get ANI and DNIS as below

```
private static void AudioVideoCallReceived(object sender, CallReceivedEventArgs<AudioVideoCall> e)
        {                
            SipUriParser CallerPartySipUri = new SipUriParser(e.Call.RemoteEndpoint.Uri);
            SipUriParser CalledPartySipUri = new SipUriParser(e.RequestData.RequestUri);
            Console.WriteLine("From(Caller party) : " + CallerPartySipUri.User + " To(Called Party)" + CalledPartySipUri.User);
        }
```